# How to introduce a name alias for a type in a template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-alias

```
template<typename T>
using Value_type<T> = typename T::value_type;
```

I get errors:

expected '=' before '<' token

expected type-specifier before '<' token

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
template <typename T>
using Value_type = typename T::value_type;
```

Just like in the declaration of any primary template, the name of the template itself is not punctuated with the template parameter list.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<typename T>
using Value_type = typename T::value_type;
```